# why onkeypress event is not fired for text box inside a table?

Tags: javascript

```
<table id="selectedTable">
  <thead>  
     <tr>
       <td>ID</td>
       <td>VAL1</td>
       <td>VAL2</td>
     </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="selectedTableBody">
      <tr>  
        <td>1</td>
        <td name="positionColumn"><input name="position" value="1" /></td>
        <td name="predecessorColumn"><input name="predecessor" value="0"/></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>  
        <td>2</td>
        <td name="positionColumn"><input name="position" value="2"/></td>
        <td name="predecessorColumn"><input name="predecessor" value="1"/></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>  
        <td>2</td>
        <td name="positionColumn"><input name="position" value="2"/></td>
        <td name="predecessorColumn"><input name="predecessor" value="1"/></td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script>
   function addEvn()
     {
        alert("event added...");
        var x = document.getElementById("selectedTable").rows[1].cells[1].children[0];
        x.setAttribute("onkeypress",writePredecessor());
     }
     function writePredecessor()
     {
       alert("WP Called");
       var x = document.getElementById("selectedTable").rows[1].cells[1].children[0];

        var y = document.getElementById("selectedTable").rows[1].cells[2].children[0];
         y.value=x.value-1;

     }
     window.addEventListener("load",addEvn);
</script>
```

I have added an event whenever a textbox value is typed.but that event is not firing.If I type number in position text box then predecessor text box should automatically assigned to the same number decremented by one. .

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> x.setAttribute("onkeypress",writePredecessor());
> ```

You are setting the `onkeypress` attribute to the return value of calling `writePredecessor()`. Since that function doesn't have a return statement, that is `undefined` which get stringified to `"undefined"`, which is a bit of JavaScript that does nothing.

Use `x.addEventListener("keypress", writePredecessor)`, just as you do at the end of the script for handling the load event.

Comment: If I have any attribute which I am return from method then only I can use `writePredecessor()` otherwise I need to return `writePredecessor` You mean the same in answer

Comment: @David — No, I don't. The point is to assign the function as the event handler, not to call the function immediately and assign the return value (which is `undefined`) as the event handler.